# Debian bash script, checking gateway by ping script as cron job

Tags: bash, cron, debian

Have next bash script **/home/admin2/wlan0r.sh** under root:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        if ping -c 1 -W 5 192.168.1.254; then
                sleep 15
        else
                echo "PING GW ERROR"
                ifdown wlan0
                sleep 2
                ifup wlan0
        fi
done
```

and **sudo crontab -l** job:

```
# ...
* * * * * /home/admin2/wlan0r.sh
```

and that doesn't work (script wont down and up wlan0 interface when wifi router reboots).
But when i type directly from keyboard: **sudo -i**, then **ifdown wlan0**, then **ifup wlan0** all works fine (successfully reconnected to WiFi AP)

What i missed up?

Comment: An additional issue here is that you're starting an infinite loop every minute, meaning that within a very short time a whole heap of these scripts will be competing to restart the AP.

Comment: did you chmod the script?

Comment: Yes, script have +777 rights

Comment: 2 l0b0is cron works like this?

Comment: Besides the PATH problem, better use systemd timer if possible. Much more flexible.